# How to create seperate mlflow custom models for training and prediction?

Tags: mlflow

My requirement is to create separate Mlflow custom models for training and prediction.
I want to create training model and use those training model in prediction model

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mlflow.pyfunc` to create a custom model.

You can find additional details of `mlflow.pyfunc` on [this link](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pyfunc.html#pyfunc-create-custom).

[This link](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html) will also help you get a overall view on models